# Cloud storage for infrequently accessed files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm creating an app for hosting files and photos. Files that have been uploaded recently will be accessed numerous times, so something like `Amazon S3` would be excellent for this.

But as files grow older I expect them to be accessed very infrequently. ***However***, when they are accessed, I still would like them to be available immediately, so `Amazon Glacier` doesn't work in this regard because restoration takes hours and hours.

Is there a storage solution somewhere in between the cost of S3 and Glacier where the price gets reduced dramatically because the files are accessed, say, once a year versus numerous times an hour, while still preserving instant access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 has an [infrequent access](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/) storage class, priced at a bit under half the cost of normal storage.

The tradeoffs you make are that objects under 128k are billed as if they are 128k and the availability target is 99.9% rather than 99.99%

Answer (score 1):

Azure offers [hot and cold storage tiers][1]
  [1]: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-blob-storage-tiers/ for blob storage,
whereby the cold tier gives the same access time as the hot tier, while giving a different cost model.